# Use temporary credentials to sign AWS SIGv4 request using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use `curl` to make a SIGv4 signed request to API Gateway, using temporary credentials from an assumed role. I have this working using `awscurl`, which provides an option to pass the `--security_token` (session token).

```
awscurl --service execute-api -X POST -d '{}' https://aaaaaaaa.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/endpoint --region eu-west-1 --access_key ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} --secret_key ${AWS_SECRET_KEY} --security_token "${SESSION_TOKEN}"
{"response":{}}
```

But I am unable to make the same request succeed using standard `curl`:

```
curl --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-1:execute-api" --user '${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${AWS_SECRET_KEY}' -XPOST https://aaaaaaaa.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/endpoint -d'{}'
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

does anyone know how to pass the session token using `curl`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a header to the request:

```
-H "x-amz-security-token: $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"
```

At least it worked for me with EKS...

```
❯ curl https://eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clusters/<cluster-name> --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-west-2:eks"
{"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}

❯ curl https://eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clusters/<cluster-name> --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-west-2:eks" -H "x-amz-security-token: $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"
{
  "cluster": {...}
}
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. But if I have to use the keys to generate a token, couldn't curl do that automatically?

Comment: The issue you're having I'm guessing is because you need to UrlEncode the session token. When I try this though, it complains "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.". Almost as if it doesn't see the session token in the query params because the access key/secret key are in the header.